# How to forcefully cast a string(generated by formating some date) into Date?

Tags: java

I have a string (Jan12) (generated by applying some operations on current date {20-jan-2012}) Now i want to convert back this string into Date format . Also the value should be same i.e the new Date object should have value jan12 and not (20-jan-2012) . Pls help . I have tried doing

```
 java.sql.Date.valueOf("Jan12") [this throws IllegalArgumentException]
```

and also

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").parse("Jan12") [By this Date gets converted to 20-jan-2012]
```

**Output required :** A Date Object having value Jan12 (12 is the year)
**My Code :** new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(s)) // It is a string which gives Jan12

Now i really want to convert **Mycode** into a Date object

```
    Date now = new Date();                       
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
    String s1 = df.format(now); 
    System.out.println(s1);    // 2012-01-20
    java.sql.Date d111=java.sql.Date.valueOf(s1);
    System.out.println(d111); // 2012-01-20
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy");
    String s2 = df1.format(d111);
    System.out.println(s2);  //Jan12
  Now i want s2 to be converted in Date object
```

Comment: A date without a year is not a date - so you won't be able to create one in the way you've described.

Comment: you want to create a date without year????

Comment: java.sql.Date.valueOf(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(S)))

Answer (score 1):

@Aditya,

If you use the Str2 which gives "Jan12", there is no date part in that string and therefore if you convert it to a date object, it will get "Jan" as month, 12 as year but it cant find "day"  in that String.

if you use below code

```
 try
    {
            Date d2 = df1.parse(s2); //here s2 is your string which gives "JAN12"
            System.out.println(d2);
    }
    catch(ParseException pe)
    {
        System.out.println("parse exception..");
    }
```

The output to the above code will be:

> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2012

notice here that day part is reset to the first day of the month

Therefore, it is not possible to get a complete date object as your original Date, the month and year are preserved, but the day part is lost.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "gets converted"? How your Date is displayed is a separate issue. Look into formatting a Date.

Comment: mycode--->new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM-dd").parse(s)); //here s is a string and the above expression gives the value jan12(a string) when s is 2012-01-17..Now i want the Date object of it which fives same jan12

Answer (score 0):

So the `12` is *day*, not a *year* - you should parse it as such. Aslo, you'll need to tell it what year this is:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMdd").parse("2012" + "Jan12"));
```

Output

```
Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2012
```

Comment: I thought your idea was simple and straightforward, but I get 1970 Jan 12

Comment: new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM-dd").parse(s)); //here s is a string and the above expression gives the value jan12(a string) when s is 2012-01-17..Now i want the Date object of it which fives same jan12

Answer (score 0):

If 12 is a year

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").parse("Jan12"));
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date date = calendar.getTime(); // First Jan 2012
```

If 12 is a day

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMdd").parse("Jan12"));
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
Date date = calendar.getTime(); // 12 Jan 2012
```

Comment: my code--new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM-dd").parse(s)); //here s is a string and the above expression gives the value jan12(a string) when s is 2012-01-17..Now i want the Date object of it which fives same jan12

Comment: Date now = new Date();  
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
     String s1 = df.format(now); 
     System.out.println(s1);
     java.sql.Date d111=java.sql.Date.valueOf(s1);
     System.out.println(d111);
     DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy");
     String s2 = df1.format(d111);
     System.out.println(s2);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").parse(s2));
     calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     Date date = calendar.getTime();
     System.out.println(date); // prints Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST

Answer (score 0):

Use the SimpleDateFormat class properly, it will do exactly what you want

```
String str_date="12-Jan-2012";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); 
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
```

Note: the formatter.parse() method throws ParseException, catch it;

Comment: new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM-dd").parse(s)); //here s is a string and the above expression gives the value jan12(a string) when s is 2012-01-17..Now i want the Date object of it which fives same jan12

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to *format* your Date object into a String representation.
You can use SimpleDateFormat for this, analog to your second example:

```
Date d = new Date(112, 0, 20); //don't construct a date like this in production code, use a Calendar instance instead
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMyy").format(d); // -> "Jan12"
```

Note that your Date object represents a specific point in time, it will always have a day and a time associated with it.
If you want to compare Dates with the resolution of a month, you have to set day and time to neutral values:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
d = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extend Date and customize it to use your favourite parse & format methods.